# Why i see that problem in xcode debugging area?

Tags: ios, swift, debugging

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

My Struct:

```
struct BlockUser: Codable {
    let id, userID, userName, firstName: String
    let lastName, totalLikes, goldStars, sliverStars: String
    let photo, email, deactivated, foundingUser: String
    let learnAboutSite, isTopCommenter, isMaster: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case userID = "user_id"
        case userName = "user_name"
        case firstName = "first_name"
        case lastName = "last_name"
        case totalLikes = "total_likes"
        case goldStars = "gold_stars"
        case sliverStars = "sliver_stars"
        case photo, email, deactivated
        case foundingUser = "founding_user"
        case learnAboutSite = "learn_about_site"
        case isTopCommenter = "is_top_commenter"
        case isMaster = "is_master"
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code with your question. Without it, we'd be unable to help you.

Comment: Add the JSON response that you're decoding along with the models and the code where you're decoding the JSON data.

Comment: Judging by the question posted so far, you may have mistakingly passed an array of dictionaries instead of a single one. Check the line of code where you're decoding the response

Comment: Yes, add the code, that causes the crash. But maybe you can check it out yourself, the debug text is pretty clear -> Decoder found a dictionary, but was ordered to decode an Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you don't need `enum CodingKeys` explicitly if the keys are ***snake-cased***. It can be handled by the `JSONDecoder` itself while decoding.

So, your `struct BlockUser` looks like,

```
struct BlockUser: Codable {
    let id, userID, userName, firstName: String
    let lastName, totalLikes, goldStars, sliverStars: String
    let photo, email, deactivated, foundingUser: String
    let learnAboutSite, isTopCommenter, isMaster: String
}
```

Now, decode the JSON like,

```
if let data = data {
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
        let response = try decoder.decode(BlockUser.self, from: data)
        print(response)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

A lot depends upon the structure of JSON response that you're decoding. In case you're still getting the issue, add the JSON that you want to decode.